# Understanding compatibility of strains

Tags: applied-mechanics, stresses

In mechanics, we have the so called compatibility conditions, which quarantee that when a body deforms, the strains are "compatible" in such a way to no discontinuities or gaps for inside the body as it deforms. Intuitively, this means that infinitesimal pieces of material connected in the undeformed body stay connected, and won't end up inside one another.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_(mechanics)):

> ..In the continuum description of a solid body we imagine the body to be composed of a set of infinitesimal volumes or material points. Each volume is assumed to be connected to its neighbors without any gaps or overlaps. Certain mathematical conditions have to be satisfied to ensure that gaps/overlaps do not develop when a continuum body is deformed. A body that deforms without developing any gaps/overlaps is called a compatible body. Compatibility conditions are mathematical conditions that determine whether a particular deformation will leave a body in a compatible state.

Reading the Wikipedia page, these equations/conditions are developed:

$$ \frac{\partial^2\epsilon_{11}}{\partial x_2 ^2}-2\frac{\partial^2\epsilon_{12}}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}+\frac{\partial^2\epsilon_{22}}{\partial x_1 ^2}=0$$

They are derived by stating that

> ..there are six strain-displacement relations that are functions of only three unknown displacements. This suggests that the three displacements may be removed from the system of equations without loss of information.

Firstly, sure, the above statement does make sense, but what does it have to do with compatibility, as I described above? Why is it that when a few variables are removed from the system, we are now guaranteed to have a deformed state where no material overlaps or develops discontinuities?

Most of other material that I've read online just state the same intuitive idea of compatibility, and then just state that the deformation is compatible when the strain is *integrable* and proceed to find conditions ensuring that. Alternatively,  it is proven that the solution to this equation can be found:

$$\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}[\nabla u +(\nabla u)^T]$$

Again, sure, we need to know that this equation can be solved to have a sensible strain field, but how do we know the solution strain field is *compatible*, in the intuitive sense described at the beginning?

**Why simply being able find a solution displacement field, or being able to integrate the strain field imply that the strain is compatible?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of the issue, and I will admit, I am as much in the dark about this as you are.

Compatibility is a statement about the strain fields containing as much information as the displacement fields. In essence, for a strain to be compatible, we need to be able to obtain the displacement fields from it. This manifests itself in various statements, all having the same essence. Let me try to enumerate the ones I have come across:

1. "The displacement fields can be uniquely obtained through integration given the strains". This is precisely a statement about the strain containing as much information about the underlying field - if integration is not possible, it means that information has been "lost" in expressing the deformation as a strain.
2. This above directly leads us to a statement about the connectivity of the body after the fields are applied. If the displacement of point $\mathbf{x_j}$ wrt. a reference $\mathbf{x_0}$ can be uniquely obtained by integration of the strain, it is a requirement that the integral is path independent. To see this, write the relative displacement as an integral:

$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x_j}) - \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x_0}) = \int_{\mathbf{x_0}}^{\mathbf{x_j}} (\nabla \mathbf{u(x)}) \cdot d\mathbf{x} \equiv \int_{\mathbf{x_0}}^{\mathbf{x_j}} \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{x}.
\end{equation}
$

If this is to be independent of the path taken from $\mathbf{x_0}$ to $\mathbf{x_j}$, the field $\mathbf{A}$ has to be irrotational (and the domain of the body has to be simply connected, which means that it cannot have any holes/overlap). This can in turn be seen by integrating over a region $\Omega$ of the body (and through Stokes' theorem)

$\oint\limits_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{A}\,\mathrm{d}\gamma = \int \limits_{\Omega} \mathbf{n} \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) = 0
$

So that

$
\int_{\mathbf{x_0}}^{\mathbf{x_j}} \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{x}
 + \int_{\mathbf{x_j}}^{\mathbf{x_0}} \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{x} = 0,
$

along the different halves of $\partial \Omega$, the periphery of $\Omega$. So we have arrived to the requirement $\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = 0$. A requirement for Stokes' theorem to be applied is that the body is simply connected, which as outlined means that there are no holes/overlap in the body! So this leads us to the third statement:

3. The strain field should be irrotational and the body simply connected (no holes/overlap).

I hope this has helped.